# Css padding 50% doesn't position element in the middle

Tags: html, css

I tried to position an image element in the middle of a grid, but when I set the padding of the `figcaption` to 50% it doesn't work. When I change this to 25% it will position in the center. Why does the 50% doesn't work for me?

http://jsfiddle.net/GDATb/6/

Comment: There's never been the need of `-ms-animation`: it appeared already unprefixed in IE ([caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation), click on Show all versions upper left). You should use any autoprefix(e)r tool to manage that for you, way easier, less prone to error, omissions and bloat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have messed up with padding property.

best way to write padding property is

```
padding:25% 25% 25% 25%; and this means
```

top padding is 25%
right padding is 25%
bottom padding is 25%
left padding is 25%

but if you use only `padding:50%` that means add 50% padding from all four sides which means cover all the area. when you use it as 25% only you can cover 50% of the area as you wanted and that is what happen on your code.

click [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp) for more info about padding's.

Answer (score 1):

First you should understand that padding works from the inside to the outside. so if you have a padding of 50% the padding top takes half the container and the padding bottom takes the remaining half at the bottom. check out [padding in w3c](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp)